# Finding coefficients using roots of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots

For the polynomial $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+c=0$, with zeros $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\text{ and }\sigma$, it is given that

(i) sum of all roots is $2$,

(ii) the product of all roots is $1$, and

(iii) the individually squared sum of roots is $0$.

Find the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Can anyone explain how we're supposed to solve this, I've been stuck on it for an hour and I am relatively new to this topic

Comment: Hint:  If your polynomial were quadratic, for illustration,  then $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)=x^2-(r_1+r_2)x+r_1r_2$.

Comment: If I were you I would call the last root *delta* so that the roots be in alphabetical order.

Comment: What have you done so far? You should write that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by factoring the polynomial into its roots. We can do this because of the Factor Theorem.
$$x^4+ax^3+bx^2+c=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)(x-\sigma)$$and by expanding this out we get $$=x^4-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\sigma)x^3+(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\alpha\sigma+\beta\gamma+\beta\sigma+\gamma\sigma)x^2-(\alpha\beta\gamma +\alpha\beta\sigma+\alpha\gamma\sigma+\beta\gamma\sigma)x+\alpha\beta\gamma\sigma$$(you can check this by doing the expansion manually and grouping like terms, but it's easier using something called Vieta's formula which is just a generalisation of this idea.)
So now we can assign these coefficients of our original polynomial with the coefficients of the new one. We now get
$$\begin{align*}
-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\sigma)&=a\\
\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\alpha\sigma+\beta\gamma+\beta\sigma+\gamma\sigma&=b\\
-(\alpha\beta\gamma +\alpha\beta\sigma+\alpha\gamma\sigma+\beta\gamma\sigma)&=0\\
\alpha\beta\gamma\sigma&=c
\end{align*}$$
Then since you know some things about the sum, product and sum of individually squared roots, you can fairly easily use their relationships with coefficients $a,b,c$ to work out what those coefficients are.

Comment: Hello! thank you so much for this, i think i rushed in too quickly and tried solving this question without vieta's formula which made the expansion incredibly time consuming. Thank you, again, for the help. and sorry if the transcript was hard to understand, its my first time using the site :(